# Audio Unit and Writing to file

Tags: macos, audio

I'm creating real-time audio sequencer app on OS X.
Real-time synth part is implemented by using `AURenderCallback`.
Now I'm making function to write rendered result to Wave File `(44100Hz 16bit Stereo)`.
Format for render-callback function is 44100Hz 32bit float Stereo interleaved.

I'm using `ExtAudioFileWrite` to write to file.
But `ExtAudioFileWrite` function returns error code `1768846202`;

I searched `1768846202` but I couldn't get information.
Would you give me some hints?

Thank you.

Here is code.

```
    outFileFormat.mSampleRate = 44100;
    outFileFormat.mFormatID = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
    outFileFormat.mFormatFlags = 
 kAudioFormatFlagIsSignedInteger | kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked;
    outFileFormat.mBitsPerChannel = 16;
    outFileFormat.mChannelsPerFrame = 2;
    outFileFormat.mFramesPerPacket = 1;
    outFileFormat.mBytesPerFrame = 
 outFileFormat.mBitsPerChannel / 8 * outFileFormat.mChannelsPerFrame;
    outFileFormat.mBytesPerPacket = 
 outFileFormat.mBytesPerFrame * outFileFormat.mFramesPerPacket;

 AudioBufferList *ioList;
    ioList = (AudioBufferList*)calloc(1, sizeof(AudioBufferList)
         + 2 * sizeof(AudioBuffer));
    ioList->mNumberBuffers = 2;
    ioList->mBuffers[0].mNumberChannels = 1;
    ioList->mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize = allocByteSize / 2;
    ioList->mBuffers[0].mData = ioDataL;
 ioList->mBuffers[1].mNumberChannels = 1;
    ioList->mBuffers[1].mDataByteSize = allocByteSize / 2;
    ioList->mBuffers[1].mData = ioDataR;

...

while (1) {
  //Fill buffer by using render callback func.
  RenderCallback(self, nil, nil, 0, frames, ioList);

        //i want to create one sec file.
        if (renderedFrames >= 44100) break;

  err = ExtAudioFileWrite(outAudioFileRef, frames , ioList);
  if (err != noErr){
   NSLog(@"ERROR AT WRITING TO FILE");
   goto errorExit;
  }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Some of the error codes are actually four character strings. The Core Audio book provides a nice function to handle errors.

```
static void CheckError(OSStatus error, const char *operation)
{
    if (error == noErr) return;

    char str[20];
    // see if it appears to be a 4-char-code
    *(UInt32 *)(str + 1) = CFSwapInt32HostToBig(error);
    if (isprint(str[1]) && isprint(str[2]) && isprint(str[3]) && isprint(str[4])) {
        str[0] = str[5] = '\'';
        str[6] = '\0';
    } else
        // no, format it as an integer
        sprintf(str, "%d", (int)error);

    fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s (%s)\n", operation, str);

    exit(1);
}
```

Use it like this:

```
CheckError(ExtAudioFileSetProperty(outputFile, 
                                 kExtAudioFileProperty_CodecManufacturer, 
                                 sizeof(codec), 
                                 &codec), "Setting codec.");
```

Comment: And if you run a function like that you see that the code is 'insz', which you find in AudioConvert.h: `kAudioConverterErr_InvalidInputSize = 'insz'`.   I love how you gave it half a dozen different sizes and it doesn't tell you which one is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Before you can do any sort of debugging, you probably need to figure out what that error message actually means.  Have you tried passing that status code to GetMacOSStatusErrorString() or GetMacOSStatusCommentString()?  They aren't documented so well, but they are declared in CoreServices/CarbonCore/Debugging.h.

Comment: I didn't know those methods. I'll try them. Thanks!